# Why do German football clubs have a number in their name?

Tags: football, bundesliga

I am not referring the year of creation, which it seems German are very proud of ([FC Schalke 04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_Schalke_04), [Hannover 96](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannover_96)).

Why do some 1.Bundesliga or 2.Bundesliga teams have the number one and a dot: **1.**

Here are a few notable examples: [1. FSV Mainz 05](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1._FSV_Mainz_05), [1. FC Nürnberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1._FC_N%C3%BCrnberg), [1. FC Köln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1._FC_K%C3%B6ln), [1. FC Union Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1._FC_Union_Berlin)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.bundesliga.com/en/news/Bundesliga/0000237888.jsp) on the the Bundesliga's website:

> Germans are traditionally sticklers for accuracy and they're no different when it comes to football. As a general rule of thumb, **if you see a '1.' in front of your team's name that's because they want you to know they were the first such club to be founded in their city.** Similarly, any other numbers that feature (usually at the end) demonstrate the club's pride in their historical roots by flaunting the year they came into existence.